# Как найти сумму элементов столбцов массива?

Tags: c++, массивы

Нужно найти суммы столбцов массива.

Но не добавляется последние элементы, как сделать?

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
{
    Sum[j] = D[mesto][j];
    Sum[j] = Sum[j] + D[mesto + 1][j];
    cout << "Summ:" << Sum[j] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Вам следует показать, как у вас определен массив и переменная Sum.

Answer (score 0):

По коду совершенно непонятно на самом деле нужно. Возможно, что-то вроде:

```
for( int i = 0; i < mesto; i++ ) {

    Sum[mesto] = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        Sum[mesto] += D[mesto][j];
    }
    cout << "Sum[" << mesto << "]: " << Sum[mesto] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая отвечает на ваш вопрос

> Как найти сумму элементов столбцов массива?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    const size_t Rows = 3;
    const size_t Cols = 4;
    int a[Rows][Cols] = 
    { 
        {  0,  1,  2,  3, },
        {  4,  5,  6,  7, },
        {  8,  9, 10, 11, },
    };      

    long long int sum[Cols];

    for ( size_t col = 0; col < Cols; col++ )
    {
        sum[col] = 0;

        for ( size_t row = 0; row < Rows; row++ )
        {
            sum[col] += a[row][col];
        }
    }

    for ( size_t row= 0; row < Rows; row++ )
    {
        for ( size_t col = 0; col < Cols; col++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << a[row][col] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( long long int x : sum ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль выглядит следующим образом

```
 0  1  2  3 
 4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10 11 

12 15 18 21
```

В программе для вывода сумм столбцов используется цикл `for` на основе диапазонов. Если ваш компилятор не поддерживает такую конструкцию, то просто замените его на обычный цикл `for` с использованием индексов.

Answer (score -1):

Видимо тебе нужно найти "Сумму всех элементов массива". Вот для примера массив из 3-х элементов. Но это решение подходит, если у тебя статический массив, то есть у него фиксированное количество элементов.

```
int a[3];

a[0] = 5; a[1] = 10; a[2] = 22;

int c = 0;

for(int z = 0; z<3;z++)
{
    int b = a[z];

    c  = c + b;

}
```