# Сумму находит неправильно что не так?

Tags: c++, массивы

Превратить матрицу `D[i,j] m,n` так, чтобы столбик с минимальной суммой элементов и столбец с максимальной суммой поменялись местами.

Сумму находит неправильно что не так?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float D[10][10], Sum[10], copD[10][10], Min, Max;
    int m, n, jmin, jmax, mesto = 0;
    ///////////??*????? ?????
    cout << "Enter n \n";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Enter m \n";
    cin >> n;

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < m; j++ ) {
            cout << "Enter D[" << i << "][" << j << "]\n";
            cin >> D[i][j];
        }
    }

    /////SUMA
    for( int j = 0; j < m; j++ ) {
        Sum[j] = D[mesto][j];
        Sum[j] += + D[mesto + 1][j];
        mesto++;
        cout << "Summ:" << Sum[j] << endl;
    }

    ////MIN
    for( jmin = 0; jmin < m; jmin++ ) {
        if( Sum[jmin] > Sum[jmin + 1] ) {
            Min = Sum[jmin + 1];
        }
        else {
            Min = Sum[jmin];
            break;
        }
    }

    ////MAX
    for( jmax = 0; jmax < m; jmax++ ) {
        if( Sum[jmax] < Sum[jmax + 1] ) {
            Max = Sum[jmax + 1];
        }
        else {
            Max = Sum[jmax];
            break;
        }
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < m; j++ ) {
            copD[i][j] = D[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "Jmin: " << jmin;
    cout << "Jmax: " << jmax << endl;
    cout << "Max " << Max << endl;
    cout << "Jmin: " << jmin << "Jmax: " << jmax << endl;
    cout << "Min " << Min << endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        copD[i][jmin] = copD[i][jmax];
        //out << "Mass : " << copD[i][j];
        copD[i][jmax] = D[i][jmin];
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < m; j++ ) {
            cout << "Mass D [" << i << "][" << j << "] " << copD[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
    system( "pause" );
}
```

Comment: В ответах к предыдущему вашему вопросу показано, как считать сумму элементов матрицы по столбцам.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти сумму элементов столбцов массива?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586157/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Позабавило даже начало:

```
cout << "Enter n \n";
cin >> m;
```

Введите одно, читаем другое...
И еще - вы сами не путаетесь в своих переменных? Давайте им "говорящие" имена - `row`, в крайнем случае `stroka` куда понятнее, чем `i`.

Разгребать ваш код не стал, проще набросать свой:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double D[10][10];
    int rows, cols;
    cout << "Enter rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Enter cols: ";
    cin >> cols;

    for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) {
            cout << "Enter D[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> D[i][j];
        }
    }

    int minidx = 0, maxidx = 0;
    double min = 0.0, max, sum;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        min += D[i][0];
    max = min;

    for(int c = 1; c < cols; ++c)
    {
        sum = 0.0;
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
            sum += D[r][c];
        if (sum < min)
        {
            min = sum;
            minidx = c;
        } else if (sum > max)
        {
            max = sum;
            maxidx = c;
        }
    }

    cout << "Jmin: " << minidx << endl;
    cout << "Jmax: " << maxidx << endl;
    cout << "Min:  " << min << endl;
    cout << "Max:  " << max << endl;

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r )
    {
        double tmp = D[r][minidx];
        D[r][minidx] = D[r][maxidx];
        D[r][maxidx] = tmp;
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r )
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
        {
            cout << "D [" << r << "][" << c << "] " << D[r][c] << endl;
        }
    }
    system( "pause" );
}
```